# Custom dropdown stays open on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have created a custom dropdown menu that displays when a link is hovered over. Works perfectly on desktop however on mobile, when a link is clicked the menu is displayed but when I click the link again the menu does not disappear, it stays on the screen.

I'm unable to find a solution that works for me, I'm not using bootstrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/n9eh6kr2/

```
<ul>
<li class="drop">
    <a href="#">Industry</a>
    <div class="dropdownContain">
        <div class="dropOut">
            <div class="triangle"/>
            <ul>
                <li>Retail</li>
                <li>Hospitality</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The dropdown menu shows fine on mobile screen for me. It works on mobile just the same as it does on desktop.

Comment: Interesting, when I test the dropdown on chrome mobile debugging I get the issue

Comment: Probably you using chrome devtools with device activated. Hover this way works slightly different.

Comment: I have deployed the changes to my website but I'm still having issues, is it possible other css is preventing it from disappearing on click?

Comment: @terryeah where did you test this? It does not work correctly for me